# Destructive quick and merge sort

Tags: sorting, mergesort, lisp, quick-sort, common-lisp

I've implemented a destructive merge and quick sort in common lisp, but the code feels verbose and highly imperative.  I was wondering if anyone could offer guidance on idioms that could make the code more readable, or more lispy.  Any other criticism and advice is also welcome.

I chose to make these functions destructive because, if I understand correctly, common lisp's built in `sort` function is destructive.

```
(defmacro insert-after (to-move pos)
  "Moves the cons cell 'to-move' so that it appears after 'pos'"
  `(progn
     (setf (cdr ,to-move) (cdr ,pos))
     (setf (cdr ,pos) ,to-move)))

(defun quick-sort (seq comparator)
  "Destructive quick-sort for cons-based lists."
  (cond
    ((not seq) nil)
    (t
     (let ((left-head (cons nil nil))
           (right-head (cons nil nil))
           (middle-head (cons nil nil))
           (pivot (first seq)))
       (do ((next (cdr seq) (cdr next))
            (pos seq next))
           ((not pos))
         (cond
           ((equal pivot (car pos)) (insert-after pos middle-head))
           ((funcall comparator (car pos) pivot) (insert-after pos left-head))
           (t  (insert-after pos right-head))))
       (append (quick-sort (cdr left-head) comparator)
               (cdr middle-head)
               (quick-sort (cdr right-head) comparator))))))

(defun merge-cons (left right comparator)
  "Merge two sorted lists and return the sorted, merged list."
  (do* ((head (cons nil left))
        (prev-left head))
       ((not right) (cdr head))
    (cond
      ;; If we walk off the end of left, attach right to the end and return
      ((not left)
       (setf (cdr prev-left) right)
       (setf right nil))
      ;; If left takes priority, keep walking along the left list
      ((funcall comparator (car left) (car right))
       (setf prev-left left)
       (setf left (cdr left)))
      ;; If right takes priority, Insert the head of right into left and cont.
      (t
       (setf (cdr prev-left) right)
       (setf right (cdr right))
       (setf (cddr prev-left) left)
       (setf prev-left (cdr prev-left))))))

(defun merge-sort (seq comparator)
  "Destructive merge-sort for cons-based lists."
  (let* ((partition (ceiling (length seq) 2))
         (left-end
           ;; i=1 and not 0 so that left-end's cdr is the start of the
           ;; right partition.
           (do ((i 1 (1+ i))
                (left-end seq (cdr left-end)))
               ((>= i partition) left-end)))
         (right (cdr left-end)))
    (setf (cdr left-end) nil)
    (cond
      ((not right) seq)
      (t (merge-cons (merge-sort seq comparator)
                     (merge-sort right comparator)
                     comparator)))))
```

Example of how to use these functions:

```
CL-USER> (merge-sort '(3 1 2 4 5 0) #'<)
(0 1 2 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (quick-sort '(3 1 2 4 5 0) #'<)
(0 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: `sort` is destructive indeed. A trick is to do `(sort (copy-list …))`

Comment: Why is `insert-after` a macro?

Comment: @Ehvince, I made `insert-after` a macro because I wanted a shorthand way to write the two lines in the body of the macro, while it also didn't seem necessary for the program to create a whole new stack frame just to do what that macro does.  I guess I was using it for the same reason why someone would write an `inline` function in C.  Is that a bad reason?

Comment: Yeah I think so: the general rule of thumb is to not write a macro if it can be a function. And for your goal (premature optimization?) see `(declare (inline insert-after))`. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_inline.htm & https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/performance.html#code-inline